# Altium: Designing a switch with 3 pads, 2 positions but only single contact

Tags: altium, library

I want to design a switch which commutes a single contact between 2 pins.
I have drawn a schematic with 2 pins.

IRL, the switch has 3 pads, one is unconnected.

I can't associate the physical design to the logical one because they don't have the same number of pads/pins.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum, in fact, it works with more pin in physical than in logical design. I didn't read correctly the error message.... Sorry.

Altium was unable to compile the lib because it was open in 2 altium sessions. Nothing to do with unmatched pads....

Answer (score 0):

First: You want a Single Pole Single Throw switch (SPST).  The switch in the Altium library is likely Single Pole Dual Throw (SPDT).  Simply delete one of the T-pins from the PCB footprint.

You need to edit the switch PCB footprint, select the unwanted pin, delete, and save. You can copy the whole library with the switch in it, or just create a Altium PCB file and place the switch.  Then use the Design-> Create library from PCB file.  Then you just edit the switch model and delete the unused pin.

Comment: Other way around. The real switch has 3 pins, symbol has two.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the part on the schematic to add another pin, or change the foot print of the device to include an unconnected copper landing pad, and hole if this is through-hole, remembering to open up the solder resist pattern.